# Lost RAID 1 on 3ware controller. Good drive booted up with old data

Tags: windows, raid1, mirror, degraded

Server is running Windows 2008R2.  Drive failed and reported degraded, but restarted and OS loaded.  The good drive is a copy from 5/2021 almost 8 months ago.

Is it possible the drive stopped copying data on 5/21?  The failed drive could it still have data from after that date?  We boot up the old drive with the controller and it shows a config error.

Yes, we have a backup using wbadmin, but the OS is reporting last backup from 5/21 and using wbadmin list versions does not show anymore versions from the external drive.

We would like to send the failed drive in for repair.  It still powers up and shows an error in the 3ware controller.  Don't have equipment to put into a non raid controller.

Comment: Do not bother, apply backup. Done. Btw., this is best practice and best practice is REQUIRED on this forum. Oh, and fire the admin (for incompetence or gross neglect) who did not realize that the last backup is from last april because he is incompetent in his job - backup schedule should make sense AND be controlled (again, best practices). JEsh, there is so muc hwrong here I have problem selecting from the list of closing reasons.

Comment: Off topic: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply. Some related topics may be asked on Webmasters or see Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?

Comment: @TomTom There is no indication that a web hosting control panel is involved.

Comment: Neglected systems eventually die.

Comment: "we have a backup using wbadmin" - there you go, indicates web admin panel involved in backup.

Comment: [wbadmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wbadmin) is the Windows server backup tool by Microsoft.

Comment: @TomTom Something else necessary for backup best practices. Backups should be immediately verified whenever the procedures change and periodically after that.

Answer (score 2):

You should not only have both RAID *and* backups, but also constantly *monitor* the RAID health and backups state. Without that, neither would help. For instance, if you were monitoring your system, you were to know the RAID broke in 5/2021, not now when another drive failed, and had a plenty of time to take necessary measures.

Now, your only hope is a data recovery service who'll might be able to pull the remaining data from the "bad" drive. You'll need to pay them, but this is the price you pay for the negligence of well known best practices.